# FMX.Grid.TColumn.CellControlByRow function

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I tried to compile file FMXTee.Chart.Grid.pas from TeeChart 9 for XE10 that used CellControlByRow function in FMX.Grid.pas for the following code :

**with TColumnAccess(Columns[Col]).CellControlByRow(Row).BoundsRect.BottomRight do begin ... end;**

I get running well when using RAD XE10 Seattle, and now I tried with RAD XE10.1 Berlin but get error message : **[dcc32 Error] FMXTee.Chart.Grid.pas(1507): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'CellControlByRow'**

Then I compare file FMX.Grid.pas from XE10 packages versus FMX.Grid.pas from XE10.1 packages, and there are a lot of differences especially CellControlByRow() function does not exist any more in FMX.Grid.pas from XE10.1.

Now, I want ask how to change the code that use CellControlByRow function so it will run in RAD XE10.1 Berlin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like suggest you replace the code below:

```
result:=TColumnAccess(Columns[Col]).CellControlByRow(Row).BoundsRect.BottomRight;
```

For next :

```
...
  var tmp : TFmxObject;
  begin 
  tmp:=TColumnAccess(Columns[Col]).CellControl;
  result:=TControl(tmp).BoundsRect.BottomRight
...
```

The above code should fix the compilation problem you’re experiencing. Could you confirm that?

Comment: Thanks Sandra for your suggestion, this succesfully.
I change code from: **with {$IFDEF D17}TColumnAccess{$ENDIF}(Columns[Col]).CellControlByRow(Row).BoundsRect.BottomRight do**
 to : **with {$IFDEF D17}TControl{$ENDIF}(tfmxobj).BoundsRect.BottomRight do**

Comment: Sorry **Sandra**, evidently I found next error : **[dccosx Error] FMXTee.Import.pas(894): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Grid'** in the following syntax :

    {$IFDEF FMX}
    (AComponent is TImageControl) or
    ((AComponent is TColumn) and (TColumnAccess(AComponent).Grid<>nil) and (TColumnAccess(AComponent).Grid is TStringGrid)) or
    (AComponent is TTextControl)
    {$ELSE}
    ......
This error around the **TColumnAccess** class like error before found in file **FMXTee.Chart.Grid.pas**. How to fixed this error?
Thanks a lot.